# changing the header in visio 2013

Tags: microsoft-visio

I have a visio 2013 file which needs to be edited. 
Whenever I create a new page, it comes with default logo, date and page number on it.

I can not even edit it or delete this logo. :( 
I just need to create new flow chart diagram without any logo, date and page number on it.

Is there any way to delete this logo of my organization coming automatically when I create a new page in Visio 2013 file?

appreciate your help here.

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Someone has set your Titles to include all pages.  If you go to Design and then Borders & Titles, you can click on the blank one at the top to remove everything.  If you right click on the style, you can change the option to put that style on every page.  I hope this helps.